# text editor content displays as white

Tags: php, text-editor

I am using text editor.  I added some text with font color white so it stored in the database like:

```
<style type="text/css">
    p { margin-bottom: 0.21cm; }
    a:link {  }
</style>

<p style="margin-bottom: 0cm;">
    <font color="#ffffff">
        <font face="Arial">
            <font size="2">
                This website is an  of New Beginning <br><br>,and many others.
                <br><br>If you would like a 
            </font>
        </font>
    </font>
    <font color="#ffffff">
        <font face="Arial">
            <font size="2">
                <b>FREE CD</b>
            </font>
        </font>
    </font>
    <font color="#ffffff">
        <font face="Arial">
            <font size="2"> of any of these messages</font>
```

Because i entered the text in white color..it stored the result also in  `<font color="#ffffff">`.i have to display this content in black color..how can i?

Comment: make a style in your web page `p{color:black !important;}`

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. Do you mean that the text in the text editor now displays as white after you edited the html to make the text white? If that's the case, keep in mind that some text editors (such as TextEdit on MacOS X) will convert html into formatted text after you save when using rtf format. To prevent it, you have to explicitly save the file as raw text.

Comment: why do you have to make separate font tags for `color`, `face`, `size` ? why not `<font color="#ffffff" face="Arial" size="2">`, or better yet do it in css?

Comment: am using texteditor..it automatically adds the style

Answer (score 0):

did you try:
either parsing the text and using php (what Im guessing youre using) conditions (for saving it as black, or in the output for showing it as black)
or simply overriding the styling with some css?

Comment: i didn;t get u..i need to display the content in black color